# DataFrame from dicts with automatic date parsing

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I am creating a Pandas DataFrame from sequence of dicts.
The dicts are large and somewhat heterogeneous.
Some of the fields are dates.

I would like to automatically detect and parse the date fields.
This can be achieved by

```
df0 = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(dicts)
df0.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

I would like to find a more direct way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='ignore'`

- Only use on columns of `dtype == object` using `select_dtypes`.  This prevents converting numeric columns into nonsensical dates.
- `'ignore'` abandons the conversion attempt if any errors are encountered.
- `combine_first` is used instead of `update` because `update` keeps the initial `dtypes`.  Since they were object, this would mess it all up.

---

```
df.select_dtypes(include=object).apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore').combine_first(df)

       date0      date1  feuxdate notadate
0 2019-01-01        NaT       NaN      NaN
1        NaT        NaT       0.0      NaN
2        NaT        NaT       NaN       hi
3        NaT 2019-02-01       NaN      NaN
```

Could've also gotten tricky with it using `assign` to deal with `dtypes`

```
df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(include=object).apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore'))
```

#### Setup

```
dicts = [
    {'date0': '2019-01-01'},
    {'feuxdate': 0},
    {'notadate': 'hi'},
    {'date1': '20190201'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts)
```

Comment: @piRSquared sure , please

Comment: bah!  should've kept it as yours.  Mostly the same components (-:  Oh well, I think we'll survive.

Comment: @piRSquared aha no worry sir :-) , since the `select_dtypes` is the key to make it work :-)